# Return all rows even when equals returns no data (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to be able to query 2 tables, and ultimately return everything from 2 columns, even when there's no match for a parameter. It's to check where a table has not been populated, the DO_TABLE has a REF, and the CO_TABLE has an ORDER_NO. There should be an ORDER_NO for every REF

So, this returns everything:

```
SELECT a.REF, b.ORDER_NO
FROM DO_TABLE a, CO_TABLE b
WHERE a.REF=b.ORDER_NO
```

The result is

```
REF         |ORDER_NO  
06191796    |06191796  
06191794    |06191794  
06191678    |06191678  
06191797    |06191797  
06191806    |06191806
```

But I want it show the REF when ORDER_NUMBER *isn't* there, so if there's no ORDER_NO for the 2nd and 4th REF, it'd look like:

```
REF         |ORDER_NO  
06191796    |06191796  
06191794    |  
06191678    |06191678  
06191797    |  
06191806    |06191806
```

Any help, greatly received!

TJ

Answer (score 1):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  If you did so, you would know about outer joins:

```
SELECT a.REF, b.ORDER_NO
FROM DO_TABLE a LEFT JOIN
     CO_TABLE b
     ON a.REF = b.ORDER_NO;
```

Voila!